# Uniformly convergent sequence of differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ a sequence of functions with $f_n: \mathbb R \to\mathbb R$, each of the $f_n's$ differentiable, such that $f_n \rightrightarrows f$, $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $f_n' \rightrightarrows g$ with $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable and that $f'=g$.

I got stuck trying to prove that $f$ is differentiable. I've tried to prove this by definition, i.e., $\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac {f(x+h)-f(x)} {h}$ exists. What I did was:

$\dfrac {f(x+h)-f(x)} {h}=\dfrac {f(x+h)-f_n(x+h)+f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f(x)} {h}$.

So,  $\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac {f(x+h)-f(x)} {h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac {f(x+h)-f_n(x+h)+f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f(x)} {h}=$

Here I have a problem (in fact, two problems/doubts): I would like to say

$\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac {f(x+h)-f_n(x+h)+f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f(x)} {h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac {f(x+h)-f_n(x+h)} {h}+\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac {f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)} {h}+\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac {f_n(x)-f(x)} {h}$.

If I could separate limits, then the second limit exists for all $n$, and I know $f(x+h)-f_n(x+h) \to 0$ and $f_n(x)-f(x) \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$, so if that is true, then the original limit would exist. My question is: is it legitimate to separate limit of the sums as sums of the limits when I don't even know if the existence of the limit? Another doubt I have is: How do I know that $f_n(x)-f(x) \to 0$ faster than $h \to 0$?, there I could have an indetermination of the sort $\dfrac {0} {0}$.

And for the second part, I don't know how could I prove $f'=g$.

Here's my second try with Stephen's suggestion:

Let $G(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x g(y)dy$.

$f(0)+ \int_0^x g(y)dy=f(0)+\int_0^x lim_{n \to \infty}f_n'(y)dy$.

But $f_n' \rightrightarrows g$, so

$f(0)+\int_0^x lim_{n \to \infty}f_n'(y)dy=f(0)+ lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^x f_n'(y)dy=f(0)+lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)-f_n(0)=f(x)$

which means $f'(x)=G'(x)=g(x)$. Is this OK?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is to first prove $f=G$, where $G(x) = f(0)+\int_0^x g(y) \, dy$.

Comment: I was trying to use your suggestion but how do I know that $g$ and each $f'_n$ are integrable functions?

Comment: Sorry, forget about the $f_n'$ (I forgot for a few seconds the fundamental theorem of calculus)

Comment: Don't make too many comments, otherwise a window will pop up asking you if we want to continue this in a chat room.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work if $g$ is not continuous.  The solution needs to conclude at the end that $G'(x) = g(x)$; however, if $g$ is not continuous this need not be the case.

Comment: You make a good point.  I don't see right now how to fix it.