# The uniform limit of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

Which of the following sentences are not always correct?

$A.$ The uniform limit of a sequence of differentiable functions is integrable.

$B.$ The uniform limit of a sequence of integrable functions is integrable.

$C.$ The uniform limit of a sequence of differentiable functions is differentiable.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *integrable*? Having an antiderivative?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553677/is-there-integrable-function-sequence-which-is-uniformly-converges-to-not-integr,
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572688/uniformly-convergent-sequence-of-differentiable-functions, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153973/sequence-of-differentiable-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of these are always correct

**Counterexample for A:** take $f_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be
$$
f_n(x) = 1
$$

**Counterexample for B:** take $f_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be
$$
f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1/x & 1 \leq x \leq n\\
0 & x > n
\end{cases}
$$

**Counterexample for C:** take $f_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be
$$
f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + 1/n}
$$

A and B are true, however, on compact domains.

Comment: And (C) remains false on a compact interval of the form $[a,b]$.  Just modify the sequence in this answer, considering $f_n\,:\,\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f_n(x) = \sqrt{\left(x-\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{n}}$$

Comment: I am confused why A is not always true. A sequence of differentiable functions will be continuous and the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous. All continuous functions are integrable, correct? Or is one of my claims true only over compact domains? Also, why is your counter example a true counter-example? Is $1$ not integrable?

Comment: @KevenSheng "integrable" generally means "having a finite integral". So, non-zero constant functions are only integrable on domains of finite measure. Indeed, the statement "all continuous functions are integrable" is not generally true, but is true on compact domains.